# jQuery selecting div issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have encountered a genuine problem that I cannot solve :x

I have a function that adds class "selected" to div which I click and changes inner html of button to ID of clicked div. However when I double click same div it removes selected class and button's inner html is not changing.

I wish if you could help me make button inner HTML set to something else when unselecting or make it impossible to unselect once selected div.

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
  $(".panel-kol").click(function() {
  var mid = $(this).attr('mid');

    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }

    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = mid;

    });
});
```

HTML is PHP-generated so I post one example from page' source

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="panel panel-kol" mid="2">
    <div class="panel-body profile white">
        <div class="profile-image"><img src="../assets/images/users/female.svg" alt="Osoba"></div>
        <div class="profile-data">
            <div class="profile-data-name" style="font-weight: bold;">Agata Jacynów</div>

            <div class="profile-data-title">Lekarz</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="contact-info text-center" style="margin-top: -20px;">
            <p>
                <small>Telefon komórkowy</small>
                <br/>666333999
            </p>
            <p>
                <small>Od - Do</small>
            </p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="07:00:00"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="14:00:00"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's button I want to change:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button id="id" class="btn btn-block" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: default;">ID</button>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is your html looking?

Comment: I mean button. Edited post

Comment: @eisbehr This code works. When div is once clicked everything works and it has selected class. When clicked twice button has value of this div's id but div has no longer a selected class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place it in the exisintng `if` and set it to whatever wanted whenever you *unselect* the `div`.

```
$(function() {
    $(".panel-kol").click(function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $("#id").text("ID"); // change the text here as you like
        }
        else {
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $("#id").text($(this).attr('mid'));
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Okay, that was quite simple. I'm a dumbo and it's to early... Thank you very much. It worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome, @user3163063!

Answer (score 0):

You could try catching double click event and prevent starting the previous function.

```
$(".panel-kol").on("dblclick", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    return;
});
```